# How to send subscriptions with only existing data

Tags: excel, stored-procedures, ssrs-2012, subscriptions

I am new at creating subscriptions. I have a report that needs to be sent via subscription to recipients in EXCEL Format. This report has 3 tables in one page which automatically will generate 3 separate sheets in Excel. 
   Now the problem is some of these Excel sheets can be empty and  some can contain data.  
  So the requirement is to send report if data exists. I want to generate either data driven subscription or create an expression that will allow me to send only data existing report to the recipients. However I cant find an answer how to do it. Can anyone direct me, please

Thank you in advance

Comment: `Can anyone direct me` google is your friend. SO helps with specific problems, not give pointers.

Comment: thanks for comment

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36781451/first-used-cell-above-address?noredirect=1#comment61139654_36781451) as an example on a good question.

Comment: Great thank you.I will edit and try to make my question more clear

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359141/conditional-reporting-in-ssrs

Comment: Thank you Jim, very useful information